# How to get user's completed badges (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, module, steam, steam-web-api, steambot

I am making a node.js bot and I want to check my friends' completed badges. What is the best way to do it? What module? (Module Steam-User only has this option for your steam account.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the official [Steam Web API](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API) with the [GetBadges](https://lab.xpaw.me/steam_api_documentation.html#IPlayerService_GetBadges_v1) method.

Example using the request module:

```
// npm install request
const request = require('request')

const URL = 'https://api.steampowered.com/IPlayerService/GetBadges/v1/'
const KEY = ''
const SID = ''

request(`${URL}?key=${KEY}&format=json&steamid=${SID}`, (err, res, body) => {
  err && console.log(err)
  console.log(body)
})
```